# How to delete a webform submission in a custom module?

Tags: 7, webforms

I want to delete a webform submission from a custom module that I've written. I'm using `webform_submission_delete(123, 76)`. The error I receive is:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   webform_submission_delete() (line 141 of
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mercury/sites/all/modules/webform/includes/webform.submissions.inc).
>   Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   webform_submission_delete() (line 141 of
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mercury/sites/all/modules/webform/includes/webform.submissions.inc).
>   Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   webform_submission_delete() (line 153 of
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mercury/sites/all/modules/webform/includes/webform.submissions.inc).
>   Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   webform_submission_delete() (line 157 of
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mercury/sites/all/modules/webform/includes/webform.submissions.inc).

I'm a bit new to module development. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are calling this [webform_submission_delete()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!webform!includes!webform.submissions.inc/function/webform_submission_delete/6) function, then both the first and second parameters must be objects. At least the first parameter is a node object. Most likely you are calling this using:

```
$nid = 12345;
webform_submission_delete($nid, $sid);
```

instead of doing

```
$node = node_load(12345);
webform_submission_delete($node, $sid);
```

and as a result causing PHP to complain.

If you have doubts on how to implement webform_submissions_delete(), I suggest you take a look [at the various functions that implement it](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!webform!includes!webform.submissions.inc/function/calls/webform_submission_delete/6) for an example.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I used:

`$submission = webform_menu_submission_load($sid, $nid);`

`$node = node_load($nid);`

`webform_submission_delete($node, $submission);`

Comment: Nice! Good to know that you were able to solve your issue fast.

Comment: This answer is not correct. Both parameters must be objects, as BWagner said in [his answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/222416/88044).

Comment: What about in D9?

Comment: the links are outdated

Answer (score 1):

Or if you would like to just do it via an external module you could also use the [Webform_clear](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_clear) module

Answer (score 1):

This is ancient now, but for future posterity:

As amateur barista suggests, you need to **pass the objects**, not just the ids. For BOTH node and submission.

```
webform_submission_delete($node, $submission)
```

Answer (score 0):

in drupal9 webform provides an option to delete the submission after a certain days

/admin/structure/webform/manage/{my webform name}/settings/submissions

[image]